# Install a .NET assembly without gacutil

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, nsis, gac, gacutil

I want to install my custom visual studio 2012 wizard with my NSIS installer but I don't know how to register the assembly. It needs gacutil.exe but this is not shipped along vs2012 as far as I know.. and it's a developer tool.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a little .NET helper app based on [this information.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2004/09/14/229649.aspx) Someone tried porting this [to NSIS](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=305741) but never got it working...